# How to transform this expression to a numerically stable form?

Tags: continuity, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, floating-point

I have this function

$$f(x, t)=\frac{\left(1+x\right)^{1-t}-1}{1-t}$$

Where $x \ge 0$ and $t \ge 0$.

I want to use it in neural network, and thus need it to be differentiable.
While it has a discontinuity at $t = 1$, the $lim_{t \rightarrow 1}{\frac{\left(1+x\right)^{1-t}-1}{1-t}}=log(1+x)$ is well defined, so I patch up $f$ like this:

$$
f(x, t) = \left\{ 
\begin{aligned}
    &\frac{\left(1+x\right)^{1-t}-1}{1-t}&, t \ne 1
    \\
    &log(1+x)&, t = 1
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

For infinite precision math we are done, but for floats this is still numerically unstable around $t = 1$.

What can be done about that? Can the expression be transformed somehow to avoid it?

Comment: @njuffa It does! The error is now small enough within 1ulp of 1 that I can tolerate it. Which is surprising to me, as I assumed most of it came from the division on almost zero, which is still present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When computing $1-t$ for $t \to 1$ in finite-precision floating-point arithmetic, the result is exact per [Sterbenz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sterbenz_lemma).

This leaves us with problems of subtractive cancellation. These can be addressed by making use of $\mathrm{expm1}(x) := \exp(x)-1$ and $\mathrm{log1p}(x) := \log (1+x)$. Most programming environments offer standard math functions with exactly those names, that is, `expm1()` and `log1p()`. Based on these, one computes:

$$
f(x, t) = \left\{ 
\begin{aligned}
    &\frac{\mathrm{expm1}((1-t)\mathrm{log1p}(x))}{1-t}&, t \ne 1
    \\
    &\mathrm{log1p}(x)&, t = 1
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$